# Is Naive Bayes sensitive to the number of training observations?

Tags: machine-learning, naivebayes

I'm using Swift (even if my question is not about language) and Python to test my ML logic. I have training data:

```
("add a new balloon", "add-balloon")
("add a balloon", "add-balloon")
("get last balloon", "get-balloon")
("update balloon color to red", "update-balloon")
```

When I try use Naive Bayes to classify a new sentence like

```
classify("could you add a new balloon") 
// Return add-balloon
classify("could you update the balloon color") 
// Return add-balloon
classify("update the balloon color") 
// Return add-balloon
```

My data set has a lot of observations about adding a balloon (about 50) but not a lot to update or get (about 5-6). Is Naive Bayes sensitive to the number of training observations? I don't understand why the classification is not performing well even if given a sentence it saw during training.

Comment: Your question is not about Swift or Python so those tags are irrelevant.

Comment: Yes I updated that! Was a SO suggestion, my bad

Comment: Oh really. I don't know what's happened maybe because I was already editing and tags where in my edit form ? Sorry about that and thanks for your time editing my question.

Comment: @Ludovic A glitch, probably. I already seen that happen. Maybe we edited at the same time. No problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive Bayes is sensitive to class priors (distribution of examples among classes). So if you have way more `add-balloon` than other categories, it will have a bias towards this class. It is normally helpful since suppose you don't know anything (no posterior information), your best bet is to try the class which is the most likely.

If your distribution is heavily skewed, you data sets are not large, your documents are short or lack very informative words (or contains many ambiguous ones) though, this can cause undesired results such as what you are reporting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the solution when I can't find more datas for a given class ? In my example (real app is in french) there is many way to say "add a balloon" but not a lot way to say "update a balloon" should I add datas like : "update balloon color to red", "update balloon color to blue", etc. It's a bit tricky

Comment: When building a dataset, you should try to have something that is as close as possible to what your classifier is expected to see. If you expect to see 10% of add-balloon instances, then you should have 10% of that class in the training set. Nothing prevents you from duplicating data if you have no other choices to reflect the expected class distribution. But be aware that crafting a dataset manually is not a proper data sampling approach, yet it may work if done carefully. The best is to have real data, and then splitting it in train/test/validation sets using adequate sampling approaches.

Comment: Ok for real data I will try that even if real datas steal have more 'add-balloon' than 'update-balloon' ?

Comment: Yes if real data has more, it is good to have more in your training data. The naive classifier will have a bias towards add-balloon, which is okay (to some extent). Eventually it is the posterior probability (the content of the text) that will determine the class, but for that you need enough predictive words in your content

Answer (score 1):

Initially, Naive Bayes depends on the size of data, but if we keep adding more, after a certain level, it's performance plateaus and a further increase in training data doesn't increase the performance of Naive Bayes classifier.

But coming to your case, the data is too small for the model to accurately learn about "update-balloon" and is predicting "add-balloon". Try adding more examples for classes which have less data and see if the accuracy improves.

In case your data is skewed and there's not much you can do about it, you can try other Classifiers or try some tricks as mentioned [here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~eibe/pubs/FrankAndBouckaertPKDD06new.pdf) and [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/papers/icml03-nb.pdf).

Comment: Pascal said "Naive Bayes is sensitive to class priors" if I add more examples, this still failed right ?

Comment: Well, Naive Bayes is sensitive to the distribution of training data among classes indeed. So, ideally, the no. of training samples across classes should be equal or in the case of imbalanced data, same as in testing/production. 

In case where you have to work with such skewed data, one solution is to normalize the word count associated with each class. Refer this: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~eibe/pubs/FrankAndBouckaertPKDD06new.pdf

Comment: I've updated the answer to include some more info which I couldn't add here due to char limit

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's helped me.